# Copy Data using a Query Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have found it easy in SSIS to generate dynamic queries using string concatenation in a variable expression. This has worked for me in generating a query and then executing that query using an Execute SQL Task. With this implementation I can easily *create* tables.

However, I am finding it harder to copy data. I execute an SSIS data flow task by passing a variable to the data flow task with a query, but SSIS fails to validate it because it can't obtain column level information (since the query is dynamic). Instead, I have tried to use an execute SQL task to obtain a result set, and then copy that result set into a table. I am stuck on how to take the result set of the Execute SQL Task, and copy that result set into a destination table.

Has anyone solved this issue before and what have you used?

Comment: Have you tried setting the **ValidateExternalMetadata** property to false?

Comment: @MikeHenderson That setting won't allow stevebot to make the generic ETL thing as described.

Comment: @billinkc, Bummer. I had used that setting once before and thought it would apply here.

Answer (score 2):

What about adding a little to your dynamic statement to include an insert?

You could make the dynamic statement insert straight into the table without using a data flow task.

Insert Into Table Name
Dynamic Select statment

Is the result set that simple that you can go straight into the table?

Comment: Yeah I could do an insert into. In my case the query is remote, so I will have to add a linked server.